# How to import pyspark.sql.functions all at once?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

`from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan`, `when`, `count`, `sum` , etc...

It is very tiresome adding all of it. Is there a way to import all of it at once?

Comment: `from ... import *` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try to use `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`. This method may lead to namespace coverage, such as pyspark `sum` function covering python built-in `sum` function.

Another insurance method: `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`, use method: `F.sum`.

Comment: For goodness sake, use the insurance method that 过过招 mentions. In the longer run, you _will_ get collisions with other Python libraries if you use naked count, sum, min, round functions and consequently spend valuable time debugging these errors.

Comment: What is the best practice: using capital F or use small case f? Is there a rule?

Comment: According to `PEP8` rules, lowercase variables (`pyspark.sql.functions`) should be imported as lowercase (`f`). In my opinion, importing as uppercase (`F`) at the same time provides `brevity and legibility`.

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
```

And use it as:

```
f.sum(...)
f.to_date(...)
```

Comment: This largely repeats the solution by 过过招, just formatted differently.