# max(list) error : Invalid argument, not a string or column

Tags: python, list, databricks

I have a list of years stored as `ints` and I am trying to find the max element and it's index.

```
lst = [2019, 2001, 2017, 2010, 2018, 2006, 2016, 2002, 2005, 2000, 2022, 2023, 2020, 2021, 2012]

val = max(lst)
idx = lst.index(val)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [2019, 2001, 2017, 2010, 2018, 2006, 2016, 2002, 2005, 2000, 2022, 2023, 2020, 2021, 2012] of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

My environment is DataBricks, in case that matters.

Comment: It sounds like you used `import *` and hid the built-in `max` with some other function. That's one of the big reasons `import *` is a bad idea.

Comment: I used `from pyspark.sql.functions import max, min` , i removed them, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This worked for me: `from builtins import max as py_max, min as py_min` to overwrite the pyspark built-in `max` and `min` functions.

Comment: The code shown will **not** generate a TypeError exception **unless** *max()* has been overridden and that's something you should never do

Comment: The better practice is to always use something like: `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` https://stackoverflow.com/a/70458115/11865956

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same Python code in the vs-code editor, and it works fine.
The environment could be one of the reasons for the error you are facing.

Please refer to the following link for maximum operation on the list in Databricks

https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/array_max.html

https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/max.html